# How to map a dynamic url to a function in controller

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, .htaccess

I'm creating a new magento module. The frontend name of the module is groupedproduct. Now i need to map a dynamic url to indexAction of the IndexController. For example the url will of the form `http://localhost/magento/groupedproducts/subcat1` This url will be dynamic for example `http://localhost/magento/groupedproducts/subcat2`, `http://localhost/magento/groupedproducts/subcat3` I want to redirect all this url to `http://localhost/magento/groupedproducts/index/index`.

I tried using .htaccess file and added following redirect rule

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /magento/
RewriteRule ^groupedproducts/(.*)$ index.php/groupedproducts/index [NC]
```

But it not working. I have checked and confirmed that the .htaccess and mod_rewrite are working by adding simple rewrite rule to a php file.

Comment: How you generating dynamic value subcat1 ,subcat2 etc. Seems based on the value subcat1 you need to change the action name?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subcat([0-9a-zA-Z]+) http://localhost/magento/groupedproducts/index/index [L,R=301]
```